# Вопросительные знаки вместо кириллицы

Tags: php, веб-программирование

при выводе кириллицы из БД вместо текста появляются вопросительные знаки. Кодировки php документов UTF-8, таблицы и поля utf-8_general_ci. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: сделайте запрос после подключения `SET NAMES utf8`

Comment: Вы бы не могли написать полный текст запроса? В PHP совсем плохо соображаю

Comment: Если используете `mysqli_query($db, 'SET NAMES utf8');`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло